# fixing a corrupted perl installation/ reinstallation on centos 7

Tags: perl, centos, admin

I am running

```
perl -V
```

and I get

```
Can't undef active subroutine at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Config_heavy.pl line 1418.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/Config.pm line 79.
```

this was after a

```
yum reinstall perl
```

How can I resolve this and get a working perl installation on centos 7

Comment: There is a drastic solution: removing then installing.

    yum remove perl
    yum install perl

Comment: The yum reinstall was perfomed a while back. I have tried yum history undo and i get no package matched to remove xxx error.

Comment: @DavidVerdin what are the greatest risks for this? I have perl version 5.16 maybe try and install that same version since it is a system perl install.

Comment: Well, no greatest risk than not having perl working at all.

Comment: Wait: is it a production server?

Comment: It is on our computing cluster and I can call it the production server. A lot of tools including slurm are dependent on the cluster system perl.

Comment: I see that rpm is wirtten in C AND Perl. So if you simply remove Perl, I don't know if RPM will still be working. You might need to try running yum reinstall perl again before trying more drastic solutions.

Comment: There are suggestions about a similar problem in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25818900/6193608

Comment: Many thanks @DavidVerdin I  ran yum reinstall perl. It does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Do you have root access? Build from source and install it as system perl (for example, in `/usr/bin/perl`). Try to build the same version as the old system perl.